# GravityForms - gform_post_render check if submitted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, gravity-forms-plugin

I want to check if my GravityForm has been submitted. I know the JavaScript filter `gform_post_render` that can be used in case the form has been rendered, but this one is also fired when the form is loaded initially. How can I check if the form has been submitted. The `gform_post_render` has an "event" as a parameter - how can I make use of this?

https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_post_render/

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the [gform_confirmation_loaded](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_confirmation_loaded/) event. :)

Comment: This  gform_confirmation_loaded is rendered, when form is submitted successfully, Link here https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_confirmation_loaded/